# Finding if symmetric matrix exists given eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to solve this problem below: [image]

I'm kinda lost on how to approach the problem. The only thing I can note is that the latter two eigenvectors are linear combinations of the first one and

\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1 \\
    1  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Not really sure if that's relevant at all or just a coincidence. Any help would be great!

Comment: What you might find relevant is that, if your given vectors are $v_1, v_2, v_3$, we have $v_3=2v_2-v_1$.

Comment: It is relevant and makes sense, but not really sure how it's relevant (sorry if I'm being dense)

Comment: Wait just realized that distinct eigenvalues must produce linearly independent eigenvectors. Thank you so much

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $A$ is symmetric, $Av= \lambda v$ and $Aw = \mu w$ and $0 \neq\lambda- \mu $ then
$$\lambda \langle v, w\rangle = \langle Av, w\rangle = \langle v, Aw\rangle= \mu \langle v, w\rangle$$

so ...? Can you finish with this hint?